# finding missing name from two lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list

This is an example to make the situation clear. 
Let's say we have two lists contain some names. I call them original (O) and modified (M) lists. Note, M has missed names. I don't have access to O, but I have access to M. What I have from O is a list , I called it O1, that follows two conditions: (1) in the case of repetition, only the most recent name should be considered, (2) the order of O1 is LIFO of O.

As an example, Imagine the original list contains O={n1,n2,n3,n2,n1,n3,n1,n3} where n1 is the first person who wrote his name in the first, fifth, and seventh position. So, what I have is O1={n3,n1,n2}, those two conditions have applied. Now, the modified list contains M={n2,n3,n2,n1,n3,n1} ( two names have been removed(n1, n3)), and by following those two conditions I can create M1={n1,n3,n2}.  By comparing O1, and M1

O1={n3,n1,n2}

M1={n1,n3,n2}

I can find n3 as a missing name because the position of n3 has been modified in my generated list (M1).

How I can catch n1 as a missing name?

Comment: Do you have access to any other structures or information? It appears that you wouldn't be able to distinguish from your example between O={n1,n2,n3,n2,n1,n3,n1,n3} or O={n3,n2,n3,n2,n1,n3,n1,n3}, because either would satisfy how O1 is constructed.

Comment: I know how many names appeared in O, in this example 8, and how many have been hidden from O, in this example 2 names, but I don't have access to O. I have only O1, M, and I create M1 by following those two conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be provided by using deque as a LIFO

```
from collections import deque

class lifo(): # LIFO
  """ Use lifo class to implement condition 
      2) the order of elements is a LIFO """
  def __init__(self, iterable=None):
    if iterable is None:
      self.queue = deque()
    else:
      self.queue = deque()
      for item in iterable:
        self.add(item)

  def add(self, item):
    """ Condition (1) in the case of repetition,
        only the most recent name should be 
        considered if item in self.queue: so 
        remove if item alredy in lifo """
    if item in self.queue:
      self.queue.remove(item)
    self.queue.append(item)

  def get(self):  # reverse since deque shows items in reverse order
    return reversed(self.queue)

  def __str__(self):
    return str(list(reversed([k for k in self.queue])))


O1 = ['n1','n2','n3','n2','n1','n3','n1','n3']
M = ['n2','n3','n2','n1','n3','n1']

# Place O1 & M in LIFO
q1 = lifo(O1)
q2 = lifo(M)

# Detect changes in position
changes = [x for x, y in zip(q1.get(), q2.get()) if x != y]
print(changes)
print(q1)
print(q2)
```

Output

```
changes: ['n3', 'n1'] => Missing names (change in position)
q1: ['n3', 'n1', 'n2'] => lifo(O1)
q2: ['n1', 'n3', 'n2'] => lifo(M)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I received an error when I compile the code. The error is: ValueError: deque.remove(x): x not in deque

Comment: @sezarsampaio--sorry, but strangely a line was missing in my code (namely,  if item in self.queue:).  Must have occurred when I edited the submission to StackOverflow.

Comment: @sezarsampaio--sure.  But, did it help?

Comment: Thank you @DarrylG. Your code perfectly works for this example, but it was only the example. So, if you change the O1, and M to O1 = ['n4','n6','n5','n3','n1','n2']
M = ['n6','n4','n5','n1','n3','n2'], then the code will produce ['n1', 'n3', 'n6', 'n4'] as changes. Note, the number of missing name is 3 for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible unless you have access to more information than what is stated in the question. Beginning elements of O that are missing will be unrecognizable when comparing only against O1 provided that the last repetition sequence is the same.

For example, Let M = {1, 2, 3}. Consider a few instances of different possible O lists.

- (A) O = {1, 1, 2, 3}, where M is missing 1
- (B) O = {2, 1, 2, 3}, where M is missing 2
- (C) O = {3, 1, 2, 3}, where M is missing 3

All of the above O lists produce O1 = {3, 2, 1} under your constraints.  So given only O1 and M to work with, and even the number of elements missing from O, there's no way to distinguish from the above cases to tell which of the beginning elements are missing. The provided inputs for A,B,C are identical.

Comment: A great argument I think for not being possible.